# Why does the Ultimaker 3D Printer has a Heater + Heater transfer plate (aluminium) + Glass?

Tags: aluminum, 3d-printing, heating-systems, glass

Why does the Ultimaker 3D Printer has a Heater + Heater transfer plate (aluminium) + Glass?

I wonder why a glass plate, and if is possible to remove the glass and print directly in the aluminium plate adjusting the heating.

[Link to the ultimaker](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-3).

Pictures:

[image: Ultimaker view]

[image: PCB Heater view]

Comment: You may want to try the [3d printing stackexchange site](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you, I will ask also there, but, I am looking for the engineering answer. BTW, do you know if I can transfer the question? @mg4w

Comment: It would work... once. Then you'd need hours of scrubbing of the printout leftovers from from the aluminium. Matter of material porosity.

Comment: Please do not cross post questions, see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). It's better to get your question migrated by flagging it. I have just done so, and requested that this question be merged with [your cross-posted question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/why-does-the-ultimaker-3d-printer-has-a-heater-heater-transfer-plate-aluminiu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heater PCB is not suitable for printing on for multiple reasons.

A PCB is not as durable as the supplied glass is, nor is it as flat. The surface of a PCB held up by the corners with no other supports would droop in the middle, and no current Ultimaker has a way to compensate for that i.e. automatic mesh bed leveling. A PCB is also not as versatile as a swappable build plate. It's a bit silly to swap out a heater every time you scratch the PCB, eh? (You also probably don't want to scratch and expose the heater leads in the PCB.) With Ultimaker's system, you simply unclip the glass plate and take it out.

Because most PCBs are not flat, as discussed earlier, the Ultimaker uses the aluminum transfer plate that you mentioned. If you simply place the glass on top of the PCB, the two will not make full contact at the center, resulting in uneven heating of the build plate. Assuming the glass and alu plates are both reasonably flat, if you set them on top of each other, there won't be an air gap between them. If you use adhesive or something to adhere the PCB to the alu plate, then you have an evenly heated build surface. And you can swap the glass out without having to rip off all that adhesive.

As for printing directly onto the aluminum plate, that's a question more appropriate for the [3D printing exchange](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/why-does-the-ultimaker-3d-printer-has-a-heater-heater-transfer-plate-aluminiu).